# Генерация диалога с помощью нейросетей (Python)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Возможно ли генерировать осмысленный диалог на определенную тему с помощью нейросетей?

Comment: Дайте вначале определение того, что вы подразумеваете под словом "осмысленный".

Comment: Так у яндекса Алиса есть, вроде ИНС.